# Why is GREP end of line is not working on this file?

Tags: command-line, grep, end-of-line

I trying the following command and it doesn't work: `grep -a '2$' text.txt`

Hope someone could explain this to me.

First the file **text.txt**. When I open it with VIM (Visual Editor) is shows [noeol] and [dos]. If I use `set list` I see $ at the end of a line, I see a lot of `^M^L` at the end of a page and als a lot of `^@`. I also see `$`.

My first 3 questions:
1. What is the `^M` exactly? A Carriage Return?
2. What is the `^L`? exactly? A line feed?
3. I read that the `^@` is a null character. Why is it there?

If I do `grep '2' text.txt` it returns

> Binary file (standard input) matches when trying to find a string pattern in file

So I do `grep -a '2' text.txt` and I got the results I expect.

If I do `grep -a '2$' text.txt` because I want the 2 at the end of a line the command fails and shows nothing.

Comment: `^M` is a carriage return. `2` is before CR, not at the end of the line. You may use `sed 's/\r//g' text.txt | grep -a '2$'`

Comment: And `^L` is form feed. In older times (ca. 1970-1990) on many printers, and some terminals like DECwriters, this advanced the printout to the next page of paper. MS-DOS commonly used CR-LF (^M^J) for end-of-line, and FF (^L) or CR-FF (^M^L) for end-of-page; Windows retained the former but not usually the latter. Use of traililng nulls was rare even on MS-DOS, but was common before that on CP/M (and RT-11). Is this file from (an archive of) some very old system?

Comment: Note that *nix tools only treat `\n`, a newline, as the line ending symbol. If you have any Unicode line endings in the file and you want to find `2` followed with such a line break char, you may consider using Perl, which is more Unicode friendly. If the suggestion in my top comment does not work, I can help with Perl command.

Comment: This is indeed a file from an old system